# Listing All Changesets and Releated Work Items Belongs to Specific Project Between Specified Dates

Tags: changeset, tfs-sdk

I am trying to write a small Relase Notes program with C#. I need to fetch all changesets and related work items belongs to specified project between specified dates.

I tried to use QueryHistory method but i couldn't find how could i give date filter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set

```
VersionSpec versionFrom = GetDateVSpec(date);
VersionSpec versionTo = GetDateVSpec(DateTime.Now);
```

Then with

```
IEnumerable results = versionServer.QueryHistory(sourceControlPath, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, versionFrom, versionTo, int.MaxValue, true, true);
List<Changeset> changesets = results.Cast<Changeset>().ToList();
```

you get the changesets you 're after.

`GetDateVSpec` goes as follows:

```
private static VersionSpec GetDateVSpec(DateTime date)
{
   string dateSpec = string.Format("D{0:yyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}T{0:HH}:{0:mm}", date);
   return VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec(dateSpec, "");
}
```

I use this in one of my own tools, originally I had found the core for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990828/how-do-i-get-who-broke-the-last-build-in-tfs-2010) (a great post by Robaticus)

Comment: This is the answer that i want. Thank you :) Now i thing i can find easily related work item. [Edit: I saw, every changeset item contains WorkItems collection. So this is very good :)]

Comment: Hey thanks @dbobrowski, but, as mentioned, I 've only copied the work by Robaticus.

Answer (score 3):

Just found out that there are several classes that inherit from VersionSpec and will do the work for you and are very easy to use. For example, there is a **DateVersionSpec** which accepts a DateTime. The full list of specific VersionSpec classes is:

WorkspaceVersionSpec
LatestVersionSpec
LabelVersionSpec
DateVersionSpec
ChangesetVersionSpec

Hope this helps.